# Upload dialogs for Firefox and Chrome now differ; FF's doesn't include network drives

Tags: networking, firefox, gtk3

As long as I can remember (and I've been running 14.04 LTS since its release!), Firefox and Chrome have both used the same upload/download dialog for, e.g., Gmail, or StackExchange image uploads. Chrome, happily, is still using it (note circled option towards the bottom):

[image: Chrome upload]

Very recently (not sure when -- this week?) Firefox has started to use a different dialog, which does *not* offer me access to my network drives (nicely mounted, accessible with Chrome dialog, etc.):

[image: Firefox dialog]

Obviously I want Firefox to use the same "uploader" that Chrome is (still) using. So my questions:

- **How do I make sure that it does?**
- Or, failing that, **how can I convince FF to offer me a network share as a location from its upload/download dialogs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Firefox versions that use GTK3 (like [the recently released v46.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/46.0/releasenotes/)). See [this Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187870) for background information. In short, the support for non-local files in the file chooser has changed with GTK3 and Firefox would now explicitly have to support remote files.

If you don’t need this feature very often, then there may be a **workaround**: you can try to find out the absolute path to your network share as mounted locally via GVFS. This will only work, if your network share was mounted before, e.g., by opening it in the file manager. Type/copy the following command into a terminal and press Enter:

```
ls -d /run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/*/
```

It should print one line for each mounted network share. Copy the line of the share that you would like to access. Then paste the line into the “Location” text field of the upload dialog and press Enter. The file chooser should now open your network share. (If you can’t see the “Location” line, then click the pencil icon in the upper left corner.)

Once the mounted network share locations are known, they can also be added to the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` file to create a persistent bookmark which the GTK3 file chooser can use – in this format:

```
file://$your_location Your Boomark Name
```

For example:

```
file:///run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=share.datastore.example.org.uk,share=share/users/thisuser/ My Shortcut
```

Comment: Excellent "workaround" - thanks! In my case (16.04LTS) the line in the bookmark file requires 4x slash = `////` leading slashes after `file:`. I tried with three, and it didn't work. FWIW!

Comment: Thanks @Dɑvïd for your enhancement edit! I had removed the additional slash because all my bookmarks only have the usual three slashes of [the file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (and they work, of course ;-)). It’s weird that you need an extra slash; I’m also on 16.04 :-|

Comment: I have just got a new machine and installed 17.10 (alpha2), a bit early. But I can confirm that I still, indeed, need four `////` after `file:` for these lines to work in my ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks entries. Perhaps others will share my experience. FWIW!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is now GTK3 based, Chrome is still GTK2 based., so that's not that easy. You will have to edit your theme or use a theme that supports this.

Since GTK3 is very new in firefox some themes can have problems, though I personally like GTK3 better.

You could add a bookmark to ./config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks, `nano ./config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` and see if that works. I'm not really sure.

Comment: Helpful info - thanks! Not a lot closer to a solution for me, but it's good to at leave have some understanding as to what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the gtk2 and gtk3 themes match so the appearance is consistent across applications.  Downloading new themes to find something that work for your preference is a worthwhile option.

Personally, I use KDE instead on gnome, and updating to firefox 46.0 forced me to change my gtk3 theme because the *oxygen-gtk* theme wasn't working.

Comment: “Make sure the gtk2 and gtk3 themes match” – I’m not sure what that’s supposed to mean, but I can barely imagine that any theme changes will fix the OP’s problem.