# Save Firefox Downloads to Network Share?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, filemanager, nas

I've asked this in the Mozilla community and it was suggested I come here for some more input.

The problem is Firefox will not see network shortcuts/bookmarks when saving a download.  I can save to my NAS from LibreOffice or Document Viewer just fine, but not with Firefox.

Yes, I can paste the share's path into the Firefox file browser window, but you have to know it, and it's hard to memorize.

Yes, I can navigate to /run/user/1000/gvfs/ and find the shortcuts, but only if I've opened the shortcut in the file browser during that session.

Both work arounds are clunky.  Any idea how to get this to work the way we expect it to?  The way LibreOffice and Document Viewer work.

Thanks much.

P.S. 
Here's the Mozilla support thread:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1279125#answer-1287651

The issue has been raised here before, but some time ago.  The thread and work around I found is here:
[Upload dialogs for Firefox and Chrome now differ; FF's doesn't include network drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764272/upload-dialogs-for-firefox-and-chrome-now-differ-ffs-doesnt-include-network-d)

Comment: Wow.  By the deafening crickets it seems nobody knows anything about the issue.  More info needed?  I've seen this behavior on 18.04, Linux Mint 19, and GalliumOS.  Doesn't seem to be isolated to just one machine.